# CKEditor Placeholder Plugin Configuration

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, placeholder

I am trying to customize the placeholder button. I wish to change its size as well as customize the image.

Could someone leave code examples of this CKEditor plugin being used? Thank you so much.

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could some just give examples of this plugin being used? Maybe that would be better. I don't have code samples to present.

Comment: @Brian Did you find any samples? I am looking especially for predefined placeholders.